# I want to split a function into two funcitons

Tags: c, pointers, infinite-loop

I have a function that gets a pointer to an expression, and through the code the address increases (expression++), I want to split the function into two because its too long, but I had to use pointer to a pointer, and I think I used it wrong, because now my code has an infinite loop. here is the function that i wanna split followed by to help functions:

```
char CalculateExpression(char *expression, char *LEFT, char *RIGHT){

int i,depth;

expression++;

if (Is_Digit(expression))
{
    i=0;
    while(Is_Digit(expression))
    {
        LEFT[i] = *expression;
        i++;
        expression++;
    }
}

else
{

    i=0;
    LEFT [i] = *expression;
    i++;
    expression++;

    depth = 1;
    while(depth > 0)
    {
        if (*expression == '(')  depth++;

        if (*expression == ')')  depth--;

        LEFT[i] = *expression;
        i++;
        expression++;
    }

}
LEFT[i] = 0;

char OPERATION = *expression;

expression++;


i=0;

while (*(expression+1))
{
    RIGHT[i] = *expression;
    i++;
    expression++;
}

RIGHT[i] = 0;

return OPERATION;}
```

and here is two help functions functions:

```
  bool Is_Digit(char *c)
{
    return (*c >= '0' && *c <= '9');
}

bool Is_Num(char *exp)
{
    while(*exp)
    {
        if (!Is_Digit(exp++))   return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

here is what I did, I defined a pointer to a pointer in the main function in that way:

```
   bool calculate_modular_expression(unsigned int modulus, char* expression,
                                  unsigned int* expression_result)
{

     char** expression_after;
        expression_after= &expression;
        CalculateExpression(expression,Left_To_Operation,
                                             Right_To_Operation,expression_after);

}
```

and thats how i changed the other functions (after split), the new function is called Left_Operand:

```
int Left_Operand(char *LEFT, char *RIGHT,char** expression_after)
{
    int i,depth;

    if (Is_Digit(expression_after))
    {
        i=0;
        while(Is_Digit(expression_after))
        {
            LEFT[i] = **expression_after;
            i++;
            expression_after++;
        }
    }

    else
    {

        i=0;
        LEFT [i] = **expression_after;
        i++;
        expression_after++;

        depth = 1;
        while(depth > 0)
        {
            if (**expression_after == '(')  depth++;

            if (**expression_after == ')')  depth--;

            LEFT[i] = **expression_after;
            i++;
            expression_after++;
        }

    }

    LEFT[i] = 0;



}



char CalculateExpression(char *expression, char *LEFT, char *RIGHT,char** expression_after)
{
    int i,depth;

    expression++;


      Left_Operand(LEFT,RIGHT,expression_after);


    expression = *expression_after;

    char OPERATION = *expression;

    expression++;


    i=0;

    while (*(expression+1))
    {
        RIGHT[i] = *expression;
        i++;
        expression++;
    }

    RIGHT[i] = 0;

    return OPERATION;
}
```

and finally the help functions after change:

```
bool Is_Digit(char **c)
{
    return (**c >= '0' && **c <= '9');
}


/*this char returns true if an expression is a number*/

bool Is_Num(char **exp)
{
    while(**exp)
    {
        if (!Is_Digit(exp++))   return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

what possibly could i have done wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why are you reinventing [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit)?

Comment: I have to write every help function in the code, i can't use ready fucntions.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Is_Num` modifies the *pointer* it gets, not the *pointee*. To modify the pointer in the outer context, you need to do something like this:

```
bool Is_Num(char ** const p_exp)
{
    while(**p_exp)
    {
        if (!Is_Digit((*p_exp)++))   return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Marking the pointer you get as `const` is also a good idea. It prevents you from modifying it, thus making sure you always refer to the same object.

Comment: well, I am trying to think about what u said, but in order to check if this is what causing the infinite loop i did what u suggested, the infinite loop still exists, maybe its because of illlegal way of reaching memory.

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani - Your infinite loop is because `depth` never goes bellow 1 in a well balanced expression.

Comment: I tried to cancel the whole loop that incldes depth, still the same problem, there is no difference in the way i used depth before and now, before it worked normally, again, it seems like an illegal use of something because i tried to put printf of values to see if something keeps getting same value, nothing was printed.

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani - You need to [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to find a logic error. Not put it up for display hoping someone will spot the bug. I told you the most glaringly obvious problems. You need to do the leg work yourself.

Comment: I tottaly get you, thanks for the advices, I will run over the code again.